# Data hidden in Windows 7 > SQL Server Management 2008 R2 > Edit Top 200 Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, edit

We are using SQL Server 2008 to manage our web content.  Half of our team has just been upgraded to Windows 7 (the rest of us still have XP).  All of us are using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.

We keep the web page content in a column called pageContent (nvarchar(max)) and we format the code with indents, new lines to assist readability.

In XP, we have been using the Edit Top 200 Rows to copy the pageContent value into an update query to modify the web page.  The Edit Top 200 Rows keeps the CRLF in place; query results pane does not.

The users with Windows 7, however, are **occasionally** seeing nothing (not null, but nothing) in this pageContent column when the table is opened under Edit Top 200 Rows. There's nothing captured when copying to clipboard. Yet XP users have no issue, the web page renders correctly and the Select query results pane still shows the value even for the Win7 users.

It does not happen on all records.  It seems to be related to the CRLF, or perhaps the number of CRLFs in any one field.  Seems to happen more often on the longer text entries.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My advice... editing a varchar(max) field with special characters using the SQL Gui opens you up to all kinds of potential issues.

I personally think you'd be better served investing effort into building a real tool to do your edits as opposed to investigating the issues to an approach that is already kind of a work-around it's self.

If you have access to anyone who knows there way around Visual Studio they could build you an editor (web or desktop) based in probably a few minutes that would be better than editing the fields by hand via SSMS.

I'm sure that isn't the answer you were looking for but you did say.... 'Any Advice'.

If I **were forced** to use the SQL Server Engine only I guess I might create a SPROC to export the column in question to an ascii file using the approach outlined by Phil Factor [in this excellent article.](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2007/07/13/33494.aspx)  (All his stuff is good).

Then when it came time to get that data back into the column I suppose another SPROC using [an OPENROWSET approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) would work.

**But again**, if it were me... I wouldn't do any of that.  I would build a quick column editor in Visual Studio with a text box, an export button, an import button and write a couple queries to either fill the text box or update the database depending on what was clicked (parameterized update query of course).  And call that good until the CMS arrives.

Comment: Thanks RThomas. You are correct: We will be implementing a CMS with a proper UI next year. In the meantime, we still have this issue which needs resolution.  Any other ideas?  My thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I updated my post with a theorhetical approach to using the SQL Engine only... but I still say build a raw VS form.